# Where can i check all the actions of Docker private registry user?

Tags: docker

When we use docker private registry we can make credentials with id & password used in "docker login registry URL". I understand that we can assign permissions for each user. For example

- "user1" can only push,
- "user2" can only pull.

I want to know what permissions are available?

Answer (score 0):

`Read` access allows users to view, search, and pull a private repository
`Write` access allows users to push to repositories on Docker Hub.
`Admin` access allows users to modify the repositories “Description”, “Collaborators” rights, “Public/Private” visibility, and “Delete”.

Please note that permissions are cumulative. For example, if you have Write permissions, you automatically have Read permissions.

You can assign more granular collaborator rights (“Read”, “Write”, or “Admin”) on Docker Hub by using organizations and teams. For more information see the [organizations documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/orgs/).